# JavaScript String parser calculator

Tags: javascript

I am working on a JavaScript where I have the string:

```
var raw = "123 + 32 − 65";
```

I am trying to build a calculator, but I'm trying to figure out the best place to start. Should I split this into an array?

```
var split = raw.split(" ");
// ['123', '+', '32', '−', '65']
```

But then that's going to be a ton of if statements.

What is the best logical way to create a calculator parser given this string?

Comment: Get a compiler textbook and learn how to write a parser.

Answer (score 0):

This is one place where it is okay to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Make sure you sanitise your inputs, and notice that it will only work for valid JavaScript. Or write your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with ASCII values, if the ASCII value of the first char of each substring (`'...'.charCodeAt(0);`) is within 48 and 57 then you know is a number, and you have to `parseInt('...')`. For the symbols ascii codes are:

```
'*'.charCodeAt(0); //returns 42
'+'.charCodeAt(0); //returns 43
'-'.charCodeAt(0); //returns 45
'/'.charCodeAt(0); //returns 47
```

Try with that. Sorry I'm not going further with code, I'm at my phone. Anyways, hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you explain how this relates to parsing numbers? You can split them up without using their character codes.

Comment: [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) returns the Unicode code point value of a character in the BMP, not the ASCII code (although from U+0000 to U+007F the characters are the same in both character sets). You do not need the code point value of the operator; you can use the operator itself; for example, as `switch…case` alternative or, more clever, as the name of a method.